# char pointer behaves differently in two different cases

Tags: c, pointers

I do

```
char ch = 'c';
```

and then

```
char *char_ptr = &ch;
*(char_ptr+1) = 'h';
*(char_ptr+2) = '\0';
```

This works correctly when I print it using

```
printf("char_ptr as string = %s\n", char_ptr);
```

But when I do

```
char *char_ptr = 'c';
*(char_ptr+1) = 'h';
*(char_ptr+2) = '\0';
```

Then it causes segmentation fault. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Please note that it didn't work in *either* case.  Both are undefined behaviour, for different reasons.

Comment: Agreed, it needs modifications in first case as well.

Comment: @paddy: The second is formally non-compilable. `char *char_ptr = 'c';` is a constraint violation. It is illegal to use non-zero integer constant to initialize a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'c'` is an integral constant which, under ASCII systems, evaluates to `0x63`.

That, and the addresses immediately after it, are almost certainly go to be invalid addresses to start poking information into.

In fact, even the first one is undefined behaviour since `ch` only has a single character allocated and you're trying to change information beyond that. It *may* work depending on how your compiler lays out memory and stack frames but it's still a very bad idea.

A more correct way of doing this would be:

```
char char_ptr[3] = "c";    // Allocate three bytes to ensure room.
*(char_ptr+1) = 'h';       // or char_ptr[1] = 'h';
*(char_ptr+2) = '\0';      // or char_ptr[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: I see, now I get it. Yeah I guess I need to use malloc in first case as well. So the assignment when declaring in the first line and the assignments in subsequent cases are different? First line is assigning the pointer/address value and subsequent assignments are to actual data?

Comment: @user883499, you don't _have_ to use `malloc` unless you want the storage to survive beyond the end of the function. Provided you make the buffer big enough for what you want to put in it, you can use local variables just fine.

Comment: There is a slight confusion I have, these two lines `char *char_ptr = &ch;` and `*(char_ptr+1) = 'h';` Why are these two assignments different? First one to a address and second one to data.

Comment: @user883499: `char *char_ptr = &ch;` creates a character pointer and sets it to the address of your character. `*(char_ptr+1) = 'h';` gets the address one beyond that character and tries to store a `'h'` character there. Other than both being assignments of some description, they really have little in common.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *char_ptr = 'c';
```

That is a pointer and it needs to point to an address which is what &ch is.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `char *char_ptr = addr` will point the pointer `char_ptr` to the memory address `addr`.
In your examples, `&ch` is the address of `ch`, while `'c'` is just a `char` value thus not a valid memory address.

Answer (score 0):

```
char ch = 'c';
```

this is a C command, that (internally) reserves 1 Byte to store/hold the character "c" in it, on an (for the user) unknown memory position (if the application is running, then on a place into the memory, that the application reserves before it is execute).

```
char *char_ptr = &ch;
```

This is a command, that:

1. declare a "array" of characters (char's), indicate as pointer with the asterisk,
   1a. the size of this "pointer" variable has the size of the users CPU bandwide (a user under 32-Bit OS, has 4 Bytes in length, a user under a 64-Bit OS has 8 Bytes in size. This is the default size.
2. with the ampsign &, you reference to a memory position - it will point to "ch", the command, you have given by ***char ch = 'c';***
   note: this is a reference, no pointer !
   As such, the memory value "c" will not change.
   As such, you can get undefined breakable/behavoiur, because you "reserved" with ch only one Byte, and the application is willing to remember this on a good OS, the application crash.
   This has the background, that you reference "to the memory" position, and this part of memory will be protected by the application OS.
   If you have luck, the size of _ptr is the same as your computer cpu arch.
   If you have luck, the operation system will copy the one byte of ch to the position to the address of _ptr.

   *(char_ptr+1) = 'h';

with this command, you "get" the address of _ptr, and right 1 byte left (counting from 0), and assign the character 'h' to this position, and override the content of the 4 Byte sized _ptr (32-Bit cpu).
This make the result "cxxx" to "chxx" - xxx stands for random bytes.

```
*(char_ptr+2) = '\0';
```

the same here:
you "get" the address of _ptr, and jump 2 byte to right (counting from 0), and assign the character 'h', to this position, and override the content of the 4 Byte sized _ptr (32-bit cpu).
This make the result "chxx" to "ch\0x".
This means, you formed a literal/string, that is indicate with a null terminated character, that is used to mark the string as to be ended there on this position.

printf("char_ptr as string = %s\n", char_ptr);

this print the _ptr (string) value from the char_ptr at its memory address on screen.
Because you have the literal "ch\0x";
You will get see the string "ch"
the command sequence \n is provided, and has a "newline" starting as result.